# Shared ChangeListener VS multiple ChangeListeners?

Tags: javafx, event-handling, changelistener

I have several `TextField`s that need to perform certain actions when focus is lost, like: trimming text, comparing it to initial one, checking it and if it's valid - saving. Which way would be better to handle it? By creating one `ChangeListener` with `switch` statement and sharing it among my `Textfield`s:

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> focusHandler = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    private String initialValue = null;

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean focus) {

        ReadOnlyBooleanProperty booleanProperty = (ReadOnlyBooleanProperty) observable;
        TextField textField = (TextField)booleanProperty.getBean();

        if (focus) { // gained focus

            initialValue = textField.getText();

        } else { // lost focus

            trimText(textField);

            if(!textField.getText().equals(initialValue)){  //text was changed
                if(textField.getText().isEmpty()){  //text was erased

                    switch (textField.getId()) {
                    case CoreConstants.AREA_SIZE_TF:
                        emptyAreaSize();
                        break;
                    case CoreConstants.NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE_TF:
                        emptyPeopleLiving();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //no actions
                        break;
                    }

            }else{

                switch (textField.getId()) {
                    case CoreConstants.NAME_TF:
                        System.out.println("Execute name code!");
                        break;
                    case CoreConstants.SURNAME_TF:
                        System.out.println("Execute last name code!");
                        break;
                    case CoreConstants.MAIL_TF:
                        System.out.println("Execute mail code!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        //no actions
                        break;
}}}}}};
nameTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(focusHandler);
surnameTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(focusHandler);
```

Or by creating separate `ChangeListener` for each of `TextField`s like this:

```
numberOfPeopleTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    private String initialValue = null;

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean focus) {


        if (focus) { // gained focus

            initialValue = numberOfPeopleTextField.getText();

        } else { // lost focus

            trimText(numberOfPeopleTextField);

            if(!numberOfPeopleTextField.getText().equals(initialValue)){ //text was changed

                if(numberOfPeopleTextField.getText().isEmpty()){
                    emptyPeopleLiving();
                }else{
                    mailInfoUpdate("mail");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

mailTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    private String initialValue = null;

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean focus) {

        if (focus) { // gained focus

            initialValue = mailTextField.getText();

        } else { // lost focus
            trimText(mailTextField);
            if(!mailTextField.getText().equals(initialValue)){  //text was changed
                mailInfoUpdate("mail");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Creating several `ChangeListener`s VS one shared `ChangeListener` what is better to use and why?

Comment: "Better" in what sense? This seems like an opinion-based question (which would make it off-topic for this site, which discourages questions without definitive answers).

Comment: Better in terms of code efficiency. I just got really confused which way to go: from one side I have multiple `Listeners` but less code in each of them, but on the other hand bigger `Listener`, but shared among `TextField`s. Which way is more code/memory efficient? Best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with option 3: Create a class containing the common code and use different handlers.

```
class FocusChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {
    private final TextField textField;
    private final Consumer<? super String> changeHandler;
    private String initialValue = null;

    FocusChangeListener(TextField textField, Consumer<? super String> changeHandler) {
        this.textField = textField;
        this.changeHandler = changeHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean focus) {

        if (focus) { // gained focus
            initialValue = textField.getText();
        } else { // lost focus
            trimText(textField);
            if(changeHandler != null && !textField.getText().equals(initialValue)) { //text was changed
                changeHandler.accept(textField.getText());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
numberOfPeopleTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new FocusChangeListener(numberOfPeopleTextField, text -> {
    if(text.isEmpty()){
        emptyPeopleLiving();
    } else{
        mailInfoUpdate("mail");
    }
}));
mailTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new FocusChangeListener(mailTextField, text -> mailInfoUpdate("mail")));
```

If it suits your needs better, you could also replace the `Consumer` with a abstract method in `FocusChangeListener`...

Switching on the `id` is a bad idea since it does not seperate the concerns in addition to using magic strings. Reimplementing the whole listener is not a good idea either since it makes the code harder to maintain...

Comment: I heard about memory leak connected with JavaFX `addListener` function, so I thought that creating 1 shared `listener` will help avoid it. Is it not right?

Comment: Also, instead of `ChangeHandler` should it be `ChangeListener` by any chance?

Comment: More objects use slightly more memory but unless there is a strong reference to the `TextField` the listener is available for garbage collection as soon as the `TextField` is.

Comment: Thanks for response! It's a perfect example of practical use of `Consumer` as well!